# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Range_error' what(): Range error: 0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Here is my code but it gives me runtime error. Basically i have to sum the values of z integars in the array for which i give values as well.

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>n;
    cout << "Please enter some integars (Enter '|' to stop): " << endl;
    int x = 0;
    while (cin >> x) {
        cin >> x;
        n.push_back(x);
        n.pop_back();
    }
    int z;
    cout << "Please enter the number of values you want to sum: " << endl; 
    cin >> z;
    if (n.size()<z) {
        cout << "wrong sum integar or too much\n"; }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<z; i++) sum += n[i]; {
        cout << "The sum of first " << z << " numbers ( ";
    for (int i=0; i<z; i++) 
        cout << n[i] << ' ';
        cout << ") is " << sum << '\n';
    }
    keep_window_open();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: How does the code recover the failed `cin` stream when `|` is entered?  Why the `n.pop_back();`?

Comment: You seem to record every other integer into your vector reading 1 throwing it away then reading a second. `while (cin >> x)` and `cin >> x;` Was that intentional? I also have no idea why you pop_back() wouldn't that mean nothing was stored in the vector

Comment: Your n.pop_back() looks unintentional. Maybe n.pop_front()?Also n remains of size 0, so no use of if(n.size()<z). It looks like that pop is not at all required

Comment: Your other bug is you do this: `if (n.size()<z) {
        cout << "wrong sum integar or too much\n"; }` but continue to do the sum even though `z` is too large.